# MySQL Python Insert strange?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I dont see why it's not working. I have created several databases and tables and obviously no problem. But I am stuck with this table which is created from django data model. To clarify what I have done, created new database and table from mysql console and try to insert from python and working. But, this one is strange for me.

```
class Experiment(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    filetype = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    createddate= models.DateField()
    uploaddate = models.DateField()
    time = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    located= models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**Here is view in mysql console**

```
mysql> describe pmass_experiment;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user        | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| filetype    | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| createddate | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| uploaddate  | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time        | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| size        | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| located     | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Above pmass_experiment table is created by django ORM after **python manage.py syncdb**

**Now I am trying to insert data into pmass_experiment through python MySQLdb**

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime,time
import sys

conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="root",
    db="experiment")

cursor = conn.cursor()
user='tchand'
ftype='mzml'
size='10MB'
located='c:\'
date= datetime.date.today()
time = str(datetime.datetime.now())[10:19]

#Insert into database
sql = """INSERT INTO pmass_experiment (user,filetype,createddate,uploaddate,time,size,located)
    VALUES (user, ftype, date, date, time, size, located)"""
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   conn.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   conn.rollback()
# disconnect from server
conn.close()
```

But, unfortunately nothing is inserting. I am guessing it's may be due to primary_key (id) in table which is not incrementing automatically.

```
mysql> select * from pmass_experiment;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

can you simply point out my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: You are catching all exceptions and so can't see what is wrong. Either `raise` the exception again, or at least print its traceback.

Comment: Unless there's some really really intelligent string interpolation going on there, you query will reach the DB _literally_ like this `insert into blah (user) values (user)` which is not valid.

Comment: shouldn't that c:\ be double escaped? 'c:\\' this might be the problem?

Comment: @ Serdalis- Yeah that was supposed to be like that. While pasting here I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql = """INSERT INTO pmass_experiment (user,filetype,createddate,uploaddate,time,size,located)
    VALUES (user, ftype, date, date, time, size, located)"""
```

Parametrize your sql and pass in the values as the second argument to `cursor.execute`:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO pmass_experiment (user,filetype,createddate,uploaddate,time,size,located)
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql,(user, ftype, date, date, time, size, located))
   # Commit your changes in the database
   conn.commit()
except Exception as err:
   # logger.error(err) 
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   conn.rollback()
```

It is a good habit to always parametrize your sql since this will help prevent [sql injection](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sql%2binjection&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFAQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection&ei=W-OiToKbEabm0QG409iGBQ&usg=AFQjCNGcGZNbIk2jM8itxItHrCja7eJ0PQ).

The original sql

```
INSERT INTO pmass_experiment (user,filetype,createddate,uploaddate,time,size,located)
    VALUES (user, ftype, date, date, time, size, located)
```

seems to be valid. An experiment in the `mysql` shell shows it inserts a row of NULL values:

```
mysql> insert into foo (first,last,value) values (first,last,value);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select * from foo order by id desc;
+-----+-------+------+-------+
| id  | first | last | value |
+-----+-------+------+-------+
| 802 | NULL  | NULL |  NULL | 
+-----+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I'm not sure why your are not seeing any rows committed to the database table.

Nevertheless, the original sql is probably not doing what you intend.

Comment: That's what I am talking about. Can you please explain how my original sql was causing cursor.execute to raise an expection?

Comment: I don't mean its not working. I just wanted further explantion about sql parametrize. But now it's clear. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll just link these here for future reference then: an [example from the MySQLdb tutorial](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples), and [PEP 0249: DB-API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)